# Difficulty with Wagtail and DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework, wagtail

I suspect I know the answer, but would like a bit better understanding.  I am using Wagtail and attempting to use DRF from a page created by Wagtail.  I verified that I'm generating a good url from axios, but I'm getting a 404 thrown from Wagtail.core.views.serve.

My implementation follows the DRF docs which ignore the presence of Wagtail.  I then found the Wagtail docs for an API (should have found that earlier!) and I am not following that guidance which is probably what I need to do.

All that said, I have tried to step through the code and I find that I appear to be getting to Wagtail.core.views.serve without having Django do a dispatch on my url (it precedes any Wagtail urls in my urlpatterns).  I'm curious whether Wagtail serve is the first step in resolving the handler (responding to a signal perhaps) or if Django has somehow passed over the url.  The issue becomes important if I have pages containing DRF that were not created with Wagtail.

Thx,
   --Don

Comment: wagtail.core.views.serve doesn't intercept the Django URL routing process anywhere besides the `include(wagtail_urls)` entry in your URL patterns. I'd suggest temporarily commenting that line out, and seeing whether your API URL still fails to be recognised (in which case the resulting 404 debug page may well give some better clues to why it's failing).

Comment: Good suggestion.  Will try.  Thanks.